# Location Module and Search api

Tags: 7, search, location

I am using the [Location Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) to add a location to a field on a content type
I am then using Views and Search Api to create an index and a view of this content type. 
The problem I have is that I cant find any way to get the data from the location to the view. At the bottom of the search index page I can add other entities such as users that are linked to this node but not the Location this is the same for Relationships section in the view.

Answer (score 1):

This was a compatibility issue with the Location module moving over to [geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield)
module allowed me to add the coordinates to the search api index

Answer (score 0):

The [Search API Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_location) module provides integration with the Location module, indexing location data.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  As per the description it states 'location fields probably work, but I haven't tested it yet' and says that Geofield fields definitely work.  From the testing I've done the Location fields don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only the Solr Search API back-end with the [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) module is supported for location searching.  In order to mimic the behaviour of the Drupal Location address field entry first install these three modules:

- [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield)
- [Addressfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield)
- [Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder)

Managing the Fields of the Entity create an Address field (Postal Address).  Then create a Geofield field with a widget type of 'Geocode from another field'.  Then select the first Address field as the 'Geocode from field' in the options.  Also select the service that will do the Geocoding (Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc.).